# How to target a class in an extension url

Tags: css

I have a website that is translated to three languages, in one of these languages I want to style an element, I can't style it using its name because it will be affected in all the languages.
the element I want to style exist in the extension /ar
I already tried this but it didn't work

```
    a[href^="/ar"] {
  display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```css
a[href="http://perishablepress.com"] {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:">Testing</a> <br>
<a href="javascript:">Testing</a> <br>
<a href="http://perishablepress.com">Testing</a> <br>
<a href="javascript:">Testing</a> <br>
<a href="javascript:">Testing</a>
```